# How to modify this code to be used for multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this piece of code that converts two lists into vertical columns and prints them:

```
team1 = ['Vàlentine', 'Consus', 'Never Casual ', 'NucIear', 'Daltwon']
team2 = ['The Aviator', 'Iley', 'Nisquick', 'Dragoon', 'WAACK']

for t1, t2 in zip(team1, team2):
    print('%-20s %s' % (t1, t2))
```

How can this code be adjusted to add a third list say `team3 = ['...']`?

Output:

```
Vàlentine            The Aviator       <team3 here>
Consus               Iley
Never Casual         Nisquick
NucIear              Dragoon
Daltwon              WAACK
```

Using:

```
for t1, t2, t3 in zip(team1, team2, team3):
    print('%-20s %s' % str(t1, t2, t3))
```

Does not seem to work.

Comment: Don't change your question after you've already received an answer. I'm rolling back the changes you made. If you have another problem, ask another question.

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
team1 = ['Vàlentine', 'Consus', 'Never Casual ', 'NucIear', 'Daltwon']
team2 = ['The Aviator', 'Iley', 'Nisquick', 'Dragoon', 'WAACK']
team3 = ['Ronaldo', 'Messi', 'Zidane', 'Me', 'Raul']
for t1, t2, t3 in zip(team1, team2, team3):
    print('%-20s %-20s %s' % (t1, t2, t3))
```

Comment: Is it possible to save the output of the print to a variable?

Comment: Yup. txt or excel?

Comment: I'd prefer it to be saved as a string variable, but I guess if I can extract it as a string from a .txt file that would work too. Just extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

Or try an one-liner:

```
print('\n'.join(map('%-20s %-20s %s'.__mod__, zip(team1, team2, team3))))
```

Also, unlike @SUNGJIN's answer, they're all processed and printed once, so you can easily save it into a variable:

```
mystring = '\n'.join(map('%-20s %-20s %s'.__mod__, zip(team1, team2, team3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "multiple" rather than "three" in the subject heading, let's get fully general about it.

To generalize the code, we would want to start with a list of lists:

```
columns = [
    ['Vàlentine', 'Consus', 'Never Casual ', 'NucIear', 'Daltwon'] # team 1
    ['The Aviator', 'Iley', 'Nisquick', 'Dragoon', 'WAACK'] # team 2
]
```

To get "rows" consisting of one element from each contained "column" list, we still use `zip`, but we need the [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to pass an arbitrary number of parameters to it; and then since we're trying to be general about how many elements are in the column, we can't unpack it into separate variables. So:

```
for row in zip(*columns):
```

Then we need a formatting operation that can handle however many elements in a row. We can do this by formatting each element in its own 20-wide string (it is recommended to use [new-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)), and passing them all - again using the `*` operator - to `print`. The neatest way to do this is with a [generator expression](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions), thus:

```
    print(*(f'{name:<20}' for name in row))
```